# WordPress Multisite Layered Admins

Tags: multisite, user-roles, dashboard, permissions

I'm using WordPress multisite for a company project. The project have 5 multilevel admin structure with about 100 websites.

The top level (5) admin (super admin) have access to all the sites.

The 4th level, which consists of 10 admins should have access to 10 websites each.

Are there plugins or tools I can use to create this role for selected users to have management access to the website as described?

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just make the Level 4 admins Administrators on the 10 sites each? Note that in a Multiste environment, a Super Admin has [capabilities beyond those of an individual site's Administrator role](https://wordpress.org/support/article/roles-and-capabilities/#super-admin).

Comment: I've not tried that out. Is it possible to assign a user to manage multiple websites on a Multisite aside the super admin?  Thanks for this. I'll give it a shot!

Comment: One of my concern is that the admin will need to navigate and remember all the sites he manages manually as there's no dashboard that consolidates all the URL together.

Comment: Yes, Multisite uses a common user pool. Also, in the back end, there's a "My Sites" menu that, when you mouse over it, will show you the sites where you have a Role set. Your Level 4 admins would see all their sites there, and be able to quickly jump to their sites.

Comment: Thanks @Pat J, this solved this issue. I appreciate a lot.