# Create custom dashboard for Multisite admins

Tags: customization, multisite, user-interface

Earlier in this thread I asked a question on how to create a multi level admin roles for multisite management. 
[Create multi level admin role](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/367115/wordpress-multisite-layered-admins)

After creating the roles and having their personal dashboard, I'll like to add custom reports to each dashboard with UI graphs. The reports should consist of all website each admin manages. Are there plugins that presently help with ease of achieving this? If not, please help with a guide to work with. Thanks.

Comment: I think you're going to end up leaning on [`get_blogs_of_user()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_blogs_of_user/), which gets a list of sites where a user has a role. (Note that, early on in Multisite's existence, the terminology was shaped around a **site** of **blogs**; later on, it was changed to a **network** of **sites**. That's why you'll see a lot of Multisite functions that have `blog` in their names.)